# Why is my svg image not found while the url is correct?

Tags: html, image, vue.js, svg

I'm using https://identicon-api.herokuapp.com/ to embed identicons in my page. You can choose either SVG or PNG. PNG works just fine, but for performance reasons, I want to use SVG. But when I use SVGs, the image isn't found, and the alt-text is displayed.

Nevertheless, the URL is valid, and when I open the image in a new tab, it's rendered correctly.

```html
<img
  v-if="iconsenabled"
  style="max-width:1.75em"
  :src="'https://identicon-api.herokuapp.com/'+e.author+'/2000?format=svg'"
  :alt="e.author+`'s identcon.`"
  :title="e.author+`'s identicon. Toggle 'show icons' to see the name instead`"
/>
```

(BTW, Yes, I'm using Vue, but that doesn't affect anything)

Comment: Can you check the network tab to see what is returned for the svg request

Comment: It seems as there's just nothing returned?

Comment: Correcting the mime type that the server is returning would be the simplest answer. You'd need to have your question have different tags e.g. heroku if you want to find someone who might give you that kind of an answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SVG has an **incorrect MIME type** set by the server. `<img>` requires the MIME type to be `image/svg+xml`, but https://identicon-api.herokuapp.com/ currently sets it to `text/html`, which causes a loading error:

[image]

For reference, here's a sample SVG with the proper MIME type that renders correctly in an `<img>`:

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Sample-image.svg" width="200">
```

As a workaround, you could fetch the SVG, convert it to a base64 string, and use that as a data URL:

```html
<img :src="'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + __SVG_BASE64__">
```

*Example:*

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    myImgUrl: ''
  }),
  mounted() {
    fetch('https://identicon-api.herokuapp.com/tony19/2000?format=svg')
      .then(resp => resp.text())
      .then(text => this.myImgUrl = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(text))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12"></script>

<div id="app">
  <img :src="myImgUrl" width="200" height="200">
</div>
```

Comment: Why then does the image display in the browser when the url is manually entered? I would expect that to fail as well right? For example, paste this in the address bar: https://identicon-api.herokuapp.com/blah/1000 or click it :)

Comment: Because SVG can be embedded in HTML but when you do that it can't also be used as an image.

Comment: So what can I do about it?

Comment: I would fetch it, convert it to a data URL, and set the `img` src to that URL.